# Django Requests and Concurrency

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, concurrency, request

I'm a little bit confused as to a few concepts regarding Django and concurrency. Suppose two users append data to the database or make a query at the same time. How do I determine what data to render for the user? I know each model has an id, but how is that associated with the user? Is this done mainly through the primary key field which you can add to Django views, or is this already done using Django sessions, and thus no need for management of primary keys or Django model ids? I've been researching for hours but I still don't understand this concept.